# Maven - issue running mvn help:effective-pom

Tags: maven

I am working through a basic Maven tutorial, and managed to create a simple archetype and run a mvn install.  However, when trying to do a mvn help:effective-pom, I just seem to get this output:

> mvn help:effective-pom [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building simple 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO]  [INFO] --- maven-help-plugin:2.2:effective-pom (default-cli) @
>   simple --- Downloading:
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter/2.2.1/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.2.1.pom
>   Downloading:
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter/2.2.1/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.2.1.pom
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 0.925s [INFO] Finished at: Mon May 13 21:41:09 BST
>   2013 [INFO] Final Memory: 9M/131M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:effective-pom
>   (default-cli) on project simple: Execution default-cli of goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2:effective-pom failed:
>   Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.2 or one of its
>   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:jar:2.2 (): Failed to read
>   artifact descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.2.1: Could
>   not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:pom:2.2.1 from/to
>   central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Access denied to:
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter/2.2.1/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.2.1.pom
>   -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run Maven using
>   the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more
>   information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the
>   following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

not much hope for me if I cant get past "Hello World" example...any advice appreciated.

Regards

i

Comment: Would you believe it...it was some "rude word" filters on my router which were stopping the download!!

Answer (score 5):

One of your network components blocks access to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter/2.2.1/maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.2.1.pom, that's all.